# How to output barcode scanner information in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a handheld scanner to scan (QR code) and (barcode) to output information on cells for sticker printing.

```
A = If Target.Address = "$L$9" And Target.Value <> ""
B = If Target.Address = "$H$9" And Target.Value <> Or If Target.Address = "$L$9" And Target.Value <> "" Then
```

The QR code will output five information on cells (H9,I9,J9,K9,L9) while barcode only one (H9).

I use `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to trigger an action when there is value on the cells.

When I scan, the information seems to output accordingly for QR code when I use A and it'll do the rest of the code but its not work on barcode, and so to make them both working I change it to B and the result is vice versa.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
    If Target.Addres = "$L$9" And Target.Value <> "" Then
        '...
    End If
        
    Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually your "question" is very unclear, we need a [mcve] with full example data. Also you need to ask something (you didn't): You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: I have to target multiple cells for QR and barcode scanning. I tried several ways and it is not working. Which part youre not clear? Im sorry :<

Comment: The whole question is unclear. The steps you are performing are unclear, it is unclear what you are asking us and it is unclear what your goal is. [Edit] your question add some screenshots and explain as detailed as possible what you are doing step by step and where your issue excactly is.

Comment: When you use the scanners on a blank spreadsheet what happens with the scanned codes?  Does the QR code naturally get broken across the five cells or does it appear in the current cell as a whole piece of data?  Likewise, with the bar code - does it scan into a single cell, or are there special characters in the code that breaks it apart (i.e. `Tab` characters)?

Comment: And how does the data look like that resulted from the QR code. And how would the splited data look like (as you expect it)?

Comment: @Paul The QR code supposed to output 5 things which is cert no, serial no, ref no, cal date, due date. When it is scanned on other blank cells it is good, but when it is scanned on a "H9" which it supposed to, it just output 3 things which is cert no, serial no, and due date. During the screen updating i can see that the ref no, cal date and due date being write on the same cells and resulted only 3. Both QR and barcode is scanned on a single cells which is H9.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The data just fine when Im using A, as i said it resulted in 3 than it supposed to when I change it to B. Im sorry for my unclear question but thats the best i can explain to you guys :(

Comment: Well I already suggested to show screenshots and show your data to make it clear.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put in some sample scanned data (you should be able to scan directly into the browser text box, just indent the line with four characters first to flick into a code style view) - just click the **edit** button at the bottom of your post, right under the **excel** and **vba** flags.

Answer (score 0):

You should add error handling to get past the workaround you'll have to do every time you hit an error: resetting the value of `Application.EnableEvents`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Goto Handler

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    <your code>

Exit_Proc:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

Handler:
    MsgBox "Hit an error: " & Err.Description
    Goto Exit_Proc
End Sub
```